# Is there a way to hide a correct Name Error message?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on writing a simple function that will take the square root of a number. The user is prompted to provide a integer. However, if they provide a string--I'd like there to be a message "You did not give me a number".

See code below:

```
def square(n):
    """Takes a square root of a number :rtype : int """
    if n == int(n):
        return pow(n, 2)

try:
    answer = int(input("...."))
except ValueError:
    print("You did not give me a number!")

final_answer = "{} squared is {}".format(answer, square(answer))
print(final_answer)
```

Works okay with a integer:

```
....9
9 squared is 81
```

With a string:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File , line 28, in <module>
final_answer = "{} squared is {}".format(answer, square(answer))
NameError: name 'answer' is not defined

You did not give me a number!
```

The error makes perfect sense since answer isn't defined. However, is there a way to just print/return the exception "You did not give me a number" without the NameError message?

Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an `else` block to the end of  your `try/except`:

```
try:
    answer = int(input("...."))
except ValueError:
    print("You did not give me a number!")
else:
    final_answer = "{} squared is {}".format(answer, square(answer))
    print(final_answer)
```

The code inside the `else` block will only be run if the `try` block completes successfully.  Here is a link to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement) for more information.

Comment: Thanks! I had else before, but I didn't indent it correctly :)